# Call a function F2 inside function F1. Based on F2 return value continue F1 execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, promise, bootstrap-modal

I want to call a modal within in a function. and based on what clicked on modal I want to continue my function.

I know it can be done by differed promise or call back. But I can't understand how to do it

my function is

```
$(".delete").click(function(){


/// call a modal
     $(".confirm").modal();


    /*
     now if clicked yes in modal 
      then continue with my ajax call
     else return false
    */


});
```

I am expecting a deferred promise or callback answer. Since I want to know how they works in this case

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$(".confirm").dialog({
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                Yes: function () {
                    // Ajax call 
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                No: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            },
            close: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).remove();
            }
});
```

---

**Edit**: here's a version with "callbacks" (didn't want to add a new answer as this includes the basics, just slightly refactored):

```
function modalwithcallbacks(selector, yes, no, close)
{
    $(selector).dialog({    
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Yes: yes,
            No: no,
        },
        close: close
    });
}

modalwithcallbacks(
    ".confirm", 
    function () { alert("yes"); $(this).dialog("close"); },
    function () { alert("no"); $(this).dialog("close"); }
    function () { $(this).remove(); }
);
```

The next step would be to make this a `$.fn.` to remove the selector part or add the dialog directly in the method.

You can pick and choose which actions to make as callbacks (eg just "yes") and keep the close/no inline, giving:

```
$(".delete").click(function() {
    modalwithcallbacks(".confirm", function() {
        // yes clicked, continue with ajax call
    });
});
```

Comment: This doesn't come as per my modal design . That the reason I expect a differed promise or callback answer

Comment: Modals aren't ajax - they don't have promises.  This answer includes a "callback", but has been put inline.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to use a own deferred:

```
var deferred = $.Deferred();
$(".confirm").dialog({
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Yes: function () {
                // Ajax call 
                deferred.resolve("yes");
            },
            No: function () {
                deferred.resolve("No");
            }
        }
});

deferred.done(function(value) {
    $(".confirm").dialog('close');
    alert(value);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mjwava8n/

Kind regards